# Is there a more idiomatic way of saying "continue your love"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Continue your love doesn't make any sense. It sounds like what someone would say if he had a really broken English, so I am wondering how I could say it better. By continue, I mean resume your love, as if it was interrupted by some life event in the past.

For example:

> The two died and then resurrected on the same country to ___ their
>   love from past lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Continue" would normally suggest to extend without an interruption, but when the immediate context makes the break clear, as it is in the quoted sentence, "continue" is perfectly acceptable. "Resume" would also be acceptable, perhaps slightly better. "Resume" would emphasize the new start, "continue" would emphasize that it is the same love as before.

One could use "take up again" with a little rewriting:

The two died and were then resurrected in the same country so that they could take up their love again from their past lives

(Note, one generally says "in" a country, or a city, but "on" a continent or an island, or a planet.)